# Converting a calculated decimal number into 8 bit binary

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am currently making a python program that is byte adder related, it will prompt the user to enter 2 integers, add them together and if it's within the range of the actual size of a byte (0 to 255) display that number and also give the corresponding value in its 8 bit binary form, for example, the calculation is equal to 1, show the binary number which python declares as the correct one.

This is the task that I am doing ~

"The program must check the input data for the data type permitted and the data value limitations (the value of the integer must not exceed the actual size of byte-coded integers, i.e. min 00000000 and max 11111111 in Base 2 or min 0 and max 255 in Base 10 for positive integers" Input in both binary and decimal format with conversion to binary

```
def add():
    Num1 = int(input("Input the first number between 0 and 255, the calculated answer must not be above 255: "))
    Num2 = int(input("Input the second number between 0 and 255, the calculated answer must not be above 255: "))

    calculatedanswer = Num1+Num2

    if calculatedanswer >= 0 and calculatedanswer <=255:
        print("The answer in decimal is" ,calculatedanswer,)

        **bin(calculatedanswer)**

    elif calculatedanswer < 0 and calculatedanswer >255:
        print("Please ensure the added numbers are above 0 and below 255")
        add()
```

This is my code so far, I have no trouble getting it to display the standard decimal number, but I really can't get the `bin(calculatedanswer)` to show the binary equivalent of it. I tried using this method that I found on YouTube.

I think my main problem here is my lack of understanding of how "bin" works on python as this is really the first time I am using it.

I have put asterisks around the line that I am having trouble with.

Comment: according to your requirement you already have the answer print(str(calculatedanswer ))

Comment: You should show the exact code causing you an issue, with expected vs. actual output.  We are guessing what "trouble" means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do have to *print* the value:

```
>>> print(bin(160))  # This version gives the 0b prefix for binary numbers.
0b10100000
>>> print(format(160,'08b'))  # This specifies leading 0, 8 digits, binary.
10100000
>>> print('{:08b}'.format(160)) # Another way to format.
10100000
>>> print(f'{160:08b}')  # Python 3.6+ new f-string format.
10100000
```

Answer (score 1):

One option for printing it would be to slice off the `0b` portion of the result, which I assume is what you mean when you say you are having problems with the `bin` function.

Try this:

`print(bin(calculatedanswer)[2:]))`

Comment: Quick question if I wanted 16bits I should have something like this? ```print(format(160,'16b'))```

Comment: `print(format(160,'016b'))` Note the extra 0 in front of the 16. That will make it so you number is padded with zeros, rather than spaces.